# How to execute YouTrack command via URL (web request)?

Tags: url, webrequest, youtrack

I need to execute some YouTrack command via web request.
For example, change state of issue by loading the page with specific parameters in URL.

```
http://YouTrackServer/issues/Issue-12&newState=Fixed
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this method: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/YTD4/Apply+Command+to+an+Issue
In your case request would be

```
http://YouTrackServer/rest/issues/Issue-12/execute&command=Fixed
```

Note, that in "command" parameter you can use any command you can apply from YouTrack web UI

Comment: Http://YouTrackserver/rest/issue/issue-12/execute?command=fixed

Comment: But, according to your link YouTrack are using POST method to do that not GET.